# How to add a new parameter in OpenGTS XML report?

Tags: xml, report, opengts

I'm enabling the OpenGTS XML reports so clients can ask the info to the server but I want to add a couple of columns so the client get a better report.

I was reading the java files and seems like is configurable but I can't figure out how.

Does somebody knows how?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know OpenGTS, but according to the [docs](http://www.opengts.org/OpenGTS_Config.pdf) (Appendix C, page 49) and [B.6) How do I enable available optional table columns?](http://www.opengts.org/FAQ.html#faq_optionalFields) you can add columns by specifying them in the various config files:

> B6) How do I enable available optional table columns? [_] Various
> tables within GTS provide for additional table columns which can be
> used for special application requirements. These table columns can be
> enabled by setting specific property values within one of the
> available ".conf" files (ie. "config.conf", etc). Here is a summary of
> the common types of available additional table columns:
>
> ```
> Account table additional columns:
>     startupInit.Account.AddressFieldInfo
>     startupInit.Account.AccountManagerInfo
> Device table additional columns:
>     startupInit.Device.NotificationFieldInfo
>     startupInit.Device.LinkFieldInfo
>     startupInit.Device.BorderCrossingFieldInfo
>     startupInit.Device.GeoCorridorFieldInfo
>     startupInit.Device.MaintOdometerFieldInfo
> User table additional columns:
>     startupInit.User.AddressFieldInfo
> EventData table additional columns:
>     startupInit.EventData.AddressFieldInfo
>     startupInit.EventData.GPSFieldInfo
>     startupInit.EventData.CustomFieldInfo
>     startupInit.EventData.CANBUSFieldInfo
>     startupInit.EventData.ThermoFieldInfo
>     startupInit.EventData.AnalogFieldInfo
>     startupInit.EventData.ServingCellTowerData
>     startupInit.EventData.NeighborCellTowerData
> ```
>
> For more information on the available optional table columns, and how
> they can be enabled, see Appendix C in the OpenGTS®
> Configuration/Installation manual at the following link:
>
> ```
> OpenGTS® Installation/Configuration Manual
> ```
>
> After making any changes to the runtime configuration to define
> additional table columns, the database tables themselves need to be
> updated to add the new columns to the existing tables. The following
> Linux commands will update the tables with the newly added fields:
>
> ```
> cd $GTS_HOME
> bin/dbAdmin.pl -tables=ca
> ```
>
> On Windows, the commands would be as follows:
>
> ```
> cd %GTS_HOME%
> bin\dbConfig.bat -tables:ca
> ```
>
> (Note: this command make take some time to complete if there are over
> 1 million records in the tables, such as the EventData table. Please
> plan accordingly.) Also Rebuild/Redeploy the "track.war" file, and
> restart any running DCS modules, so that these modules will also pick
> up the new table column changes.

Source: http://www.opengts.org/FAQ.html#faq_optionalFields

Comment: Thanks, The columns already exists. I just "navigate" inside of every called subroutine until found where the XML is generated and modified it. I also thinks that this is modifiable by some config file but none, of the ones I read it, help me out, all of them seems to belong to the web UI reports, not the XML report.

Comment: @E_Blue I see you can add OptionalFieldHandlers in StartupInit (or an own class) https://github.com/Peter2121/OpenGTS/blob/master/OpenGTS/src/org/opengts/StartupInit.java , but it seems those are not used when writing XML output. https://github.com/Peter2121/OpenGTS/blob/24dbc5b64be630c3e4814cdcad2a7e7d978b191d/OpenGTS/src/org/opengts/db/EventUtil.java#L2657 Maybe give it a shot on SourceForge forum? https://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/ I'm sorry I'm not of any help other than this.

Comment: Don't worry, is running now as I need.